# increase response size of wcf

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, web-config

wcf fails to retrieve dataset with more than 100 rows. it shows message "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element." 
but inside web.config for wcf project i had made binding as shown below

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
             maxBufferSize="20000000"
             maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_ILabelService" contract="LabelService.ILabelService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILabelService"/>
</client>

<services>
  <service name="projectname.Service1"   behaviorConfiguration="projectname.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="projectname.IService1">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"   contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="projectname.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>          
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Please help.

Comment: Your code is not visible, because you've not added it. Please edit your post and add necessary code, you're talking about.

Comment: Do you have the same quota settings on the client and server ? A common mistake is that you have increased quota only in the config for the server and client still can only send 65 kB (or opposite)

Comment: what does that mean? presently am running it locally,i only change in web.config

Comment: I meant that you need to connect to your service right ? And how is the connection done ?

Comment: till now i haven't host service on my ftp.can u explain me the scenario of quota setting for client and server side.

Comment: Quota is simple - for client it means the size of message that can be send - for server it is the size of message that can be received. That is why there can be an inconsistency. Can you post how do you connect to the service ?

Comment: inside web.config as <client>
      <endpoint
          address="http://localhost:2736/Service1.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSBigQuotaConfig"
          contract="ISomeServiceContract" />
    </client>

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILabelService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="3145728" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="3145728" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="3145728" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILabelService" contract="LabelService.ILabelService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILabelService"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Edit**

You must set your endpoint to binding name. Try this in your config.
Notice: You **must set** `contract` to your service class name with full namespace structure and `bindingConfiguration` to your binding counfiguration `name`.

```
<client>
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" contract="YourNamespace.YourServiceClassName" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILabelService"/>
</client>
```

Comment: Do you have set up properly binding configuration?    bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Username"

Comment: ya,does any other setting require

Comment: This is what I have set on the client side. On the server side I have no spacial settings...