# How to return datatable form wcf rest services?

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

I want to return datatable  form wcf rest service to  c# form,but following error raised when returning datatable form server to client.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: Why would you need to return a DataTable and not a traditional Collection/List ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got Solution to this problem.
When we return datatable form wcf rest Services then serialization problem occur with datatable.

```
           to avoid this problem convert datatable in to json stirg,and return this string to client side.
               on the client side convert this string to datatable.
```

Server Side Code:

```
       public string GetAssetRegisterDataTableBySp(ParameterDto parameters)
    {
        string jsonString="";
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM ReportDisplaySetting where Display= 'true'");
        var DisplayColumnSetting = repositoryReportDisplaySetting.ExecuteRawQuery<ReportDisplaySetting>(query).ToList();
        List<string> selectedColumn = DisplayColumnSetting.Select(C => C.ColumnName).ToList();
        string columnOfString = (string.Join(",", selectedColumn.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));

        List<string> locationIds = new List<string>();
        if (parameters.locationId == 0)
        {
            locationIds = repository.All<CompanyLocationMaster>().AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.CompanyID == parameters.companyId && x.IsActive == true).Select(x => x.LocationID.ToString()).ToList();
        }
        string locationString = "";
        if (locationIds.Count() > 0)
        {
            locationString = string.Join(",", locationIds.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            locationString = parameters.locationId.ToString();
        }
        var report = new AssetrakRepository<AssetRegisterReport>();
        DataTable taggingReport = report.GetAssetRegisterReportBySP(parameters.companyId, locationString, columnOfString);
        string strColumns = columnOfString;
        var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
        if (taggingReport.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            JSONString.Append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < taggingReport.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                JSONString.Append("{");
                for (int j = 0; j < taggingReport.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (j < taggingReport.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + taggingReport.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + taggingReport.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(","," ") + "\",");
                    }
                    else if (j == taggingReport.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        JSONString.Append("\"" + taggingReport.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString() + "\":" + "\"" + taggingReport.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(",", " ") + "\"");
                    }
                }
                if (i == taggingReport.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    JSONString.Append("}");
                }
                else
                {
                    JSONString.Append("},");
                }
            }
            JSONString.Append("]");

        }
        jsonString=JSONString.ToString();


        return jsonString;
    }
```

Client Side Code:

```
        DataTable dt = ConvertJSONToDataTable(jsonString);


       protected DataTable ConvertJSONToDataTable(string jsonString)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //strip out bad characters
        string[] jsonParts = Regex.Split(jsonString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", ""), "},{");

        //hold column names
        List<string> dtColumns = new List<string>();

        //get columns
        foreach (string jp in jsonParts)
        {
            //only loop thru once to get column names
            string[] propData = Regex.Split(jp.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            foreach (string rowData in propData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                    string n = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1);
                    string v = rowData.Substring(idx + 1);
                    if (!dtColumns.Contains(n))
                    {
                        dtColumns.Add(n.Replace("\"", ""));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error Parsing Column Name : {0}", rowData));
                }

            }
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
        }

        //build dt
        foreach (string c in dtColumns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(c);
        }
        //get table data
        foreach (string jp in jsonParts)
        {
            string[] propData = Regex.Split(jp.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""), ",");
            DataRow nr = dt.NewRow();
            foreach (string rowData in propData)
            {
                try
                {
                    int idx = rowData.IndexOf(":");
                    string n = rowData.Substring(0, idx - 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    string v = rowData.Substring(idx + 1).Replace("\"", "");
                    nr[n] = v;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            dt.Rows.Add(nr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, that the problem is, that the size of the datatable is too big. A serialized datatable is pretty complex, so the response length or depth can overflow. You can try to config this.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717580/increase-response-size-of-wcf)

But my suggestion is: don not respond with a datatable through webservice :) You should not know, who on the other side listens.

Comment: can i use any other object like datatable

Comment: Yes! You should make your own class for the communication. This class has to have simple properties like Name {get; set; } etc.

Comment: And then send a list of object!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for your problem please refer this blog and follow these steps i experienced similar issue [Remote Host Connectivity](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host/) and sample code snippet for returning data table.

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable GetBankdtls(string pm_Action, string pm_bankid, string pm_name, string pm_Accno, string pm_branch, string pm_VidStr)
    {
        MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[6];
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Bank");
        cn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        try
        {
            string query = "DML1_getbank_Sp";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_Action", pm_Action);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_bankid", pm_bankid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_name", pm_name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_Accno", pm_Accno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_branch", pm_branch);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pm_VidStr", pm_VidStr);               
            cn.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

and make sure your connection should be open and at the end it should close.